# Questions with invisible titles can be posted by using soft hyphens

Tags: bug, user-interface, title

Over at Arqade, we just received [this question without a title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354483) (now deleted, 10k reputation only). The title is made entirely out of soft hyphens, which are invisible. Such a question can't be clicked on and accessed from any list that only shows the title. I *highly doubt* this behaviour is intended, so I'm reporting this as a bug.

Comment: It does have a title, it's just a title of only soft hyphens (which are invisible).

Comment: Disallowing post titles to consist entirely of soft hyphens is more of a feature request IMO.

Comment: Maybe if this behaviour is intended. I can't imagine it is.

Comment: Hence, @animuson, there is no visible title: problem. Unclickable: another problem.

Comment: @Jedrek I get that. I was merely pointing out that it did have a title, whereas the initial question assumed it was posted without one at all.

Comment: A similar question was demonstrated/asked [here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325463) a while back, it's deleted (10+K to see).